# SQLAlchemy load_only on parent model

Tags: python, sql, orm, sqlalchemy

When eager loading a child relationship, how can I only load few columns of the parent model:

This works if I only need `title` column of the `chapters` model:

```
session.query(Book)\
    .options(joinedload('chapters').load_only('title'))
```

But this throws an error:

```
session.query(Book.author)\
    .options(joinedload('chapters').load_only('title'))
```

> Query has only expression-based entities - can't find property named
>   'chapters'.

In other words I want this SQL in ORM syntax:

```
SELECT 
    books.author,
    chapters.title,
FROM 
    books JOIN chapters ON book.id = chapters.book_id
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error message says you're only selecting `Book.author`, instead of instances of `Book`. Where is `chapters` going to go if all it's returning is a list of strings (for `author`).

You can either do:

```
session.query(Book.author, Chapter.title).select_from(Book).join(Book.chapters)
```

or

```
session.query(Book).options(load_only("author"), joinedload("chapters").load_only("title"))
```