# SQLAlchemy joinedload returning null for join

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to use joinedload in SQLAlchemy to join tables but the child table is always returning null.

The first table is:

```
class User(SqlAlchemyBase):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id: str = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    created_date: datetime = sa.Column(sa.DateTime, default=datetime.now, index=True)
    last_modified: datetime = sa.Column(sa.DateTime, default=datetime.now, index=True)
    first_name: str = sa.Column(sa.String, nullable=False)
    last_name: str = sa.Column(sa.String, nullable=False)
    email: str = sa.Column(sa.String, index=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    hashed_password: str = sa.Column(sa.String, index=True, nullable=False)
    user_role_id: int = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('user_roles.id'), nullable=False)
    user_role = orm.relation('UserRole', back_populates='users')
    last_login: datetime = sa.Column(sa.DateTime, default=datetime.now)
```

And the second table is:

```
class UserRole(SqlAlchemyBase):
    __tablename__ = 'user_roles'

    id: str = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    created_date: datetime = sa.Column(sa.DateTime, default=datetime.now, index=True)
    last_modified: datetime = sa.Column(sa.DateTime, default=datetime.now, index=True)
    role: str = sa.Column(sa.String, nullable=False, unique=True, index=True)
    users: List[User] = (orm.relation('User', back_populates='user_role'))
```

Then the query is:

```
user = session.query(User).options(joinedload(User.user_role)).filter(User.id == id).first()
```

When the query is run the information for the user is returned, but role is null. I have also tried removing the filter and returning all records, but null is still returned for all of the roles. My guess is there is something wrong with the way I have my relations set, but I don't know what to change to make it work. When I manually write a SQL query in the database I get records with the tables joined and the role populated so I know a join should return a role.

Update:
I have found that the join is returning a UserRole object instead of the role value itself. So now I am trying to figure out how to get the value instead of the object.

Comment: I am able to access the value with `user.user_role.role`. I don't need all of the user_role data for this join so I wish I could only return the role value and not the whole object. At least I have it working now.

Comment: You can do just that, either using joined eager loading, or by just querying for `User, UserRole.role`. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39552809/sqlalchemy-load-only-on-parent-model for how to use `load_only`.

Comment: Thanks, this did it